# Fuse.js library - Order results alphabetically

Tags: javascript, list, alphabetical, fuse.js

I'm using Kiro Risk's `Fuse.js` to search a bunch of objects within an array. I don't know exactly how its algorythm works, but I can see that uses a score to sort the result list depending on the word match.

I looked if it had any property for these cases but does not.  **Fuse.js url:** http://fusejs.io/

Someone had been in the same situation and knows a trick, or should be better to get Fuse result and then pass it into another function to sort it alphabetically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, I just parsed the objects result and pushed to an array. Then I just used the javascript function `sort()` to sort it alphabetically.

```
result = result.sort();
```